# mysql errors on os x yosemite after restart

Tags: mysql, homebrew, osx-yosemite

Over the weekend I started having all kinds of problems with mysql. I upgraded to Yosemite a while ago and was able to get mysql working. But all of a sudden, my computer is shutting down when I put it to sleep, and when I turn it on in the morning, mysql won't start.

In order to fix this over the weekend, I reinstalled mysql via homebrew, which also required porting over my data/ files and updating the permissions correctly – kind of a pain. I'd rather not do that again.

When I try to restart mysql from the command line I get (There is no shsair.local.pid file btw):

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/shsair.local.pid)
```

I eventually got things to work by updating my.cnf to include:

```
innodb_force_recovery = 6 (I have no idea what that does or if I should keep it)
```

But just to see if it was working or not, I tried to start and stop mysql with:

```
mysql.server stop
```

and it just hangs. I see this same behavior if I try to restart the computer (it hangs for a long time before shutting off, and I assume because it's trying to shut down mysql.

I'm up for trying any changes to configurations, but it is very important I keep the data/ files as I have years of database work in there.

Thanks!